# Gulp: enclose gulp-babel result in unnamed function

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have multiple files which I join together and transpile with `gulp-babel`. I'd like to put all the results in an anonymous namespace function:

```
(function() {

    // my file.js content inside

})();
```

What I have tried was:

```
gulp.src([
    './open-scope.js', 
    './file-1.js',
    './file-2.js',
    './file-3.js',
    './close-scope.js' 
])
.pipe(gp_concat('file.js'))
.pipe(babel({ presets: ['env'] }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('static/general/es6/html'));
```

My *open-scope.js* :

```
(function() {
```

My *close-scope.js* :

```
})();
```

But the `.pipe(babel())` part prefixes the transpiled file with variable `_createClass` and function `_classCallCheck` and I don't want them in the global scope.

My guess is that I need to

```
.pipe(prepend('open-scope.js')).pipe(append('close-scope.js'))
```

between my `.pipe(babel())` and `.pipe(gulp.dest())`.

I do know how to concatenate files using `fs`, but I want the gulp solution.